# 'ora-12505' error while connecting to Oracle XE database via SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

Whilst connecting to Oracle XE Database via SQL Developer I get the *ora-12505* error, seen below

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Your image didn't link properly. I'd like to edit it in for you, if you could link it

Comment: im unable to add the image :(

Comment: You are allowed to add images when you have 10 reputation points. Can you describe the issue instead? Or, upload the image somewhere and I'll edit it in to your question for you.

Comment: saying tat i need atleast 10 reputations to add the image.. :(

Comment: i hosted the file in below link..                                           http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=16xjafyJaHOI5NGd05qkhb01UJKtG30

Comment: @Robotnik..any clue on the error

Comment: Hey, sorry I got pulled into a meeting. I've edited in the picture for you. It says that the TS:listener doesn't know about the SID, perhaps have a look at that? Sorry, I'm not entirely sure of what the problem is - perhaps someone with more experience in Oracle XE server will be able to help

Comment: @samapti can u please help me